# Historical intraday data for altcoins that can be exported?

Tags: altcoin, bitcoin-cash, historical-trade-data

I've been looking around lately for historical data, like opening price, closing, high, low etc for altcoins. All I have come up with is daily data or higher, but what I need is like 5, 10, 15 minutes etc.

I need to be able to have data for at least a few weeks back. And I need to be able to export it as a CSV file or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try my website at [cryptodatasets.com](http://cryptodatasets.com) which has raw and sampled historical data for BTC, ETH and LTC in .csv format.